# Matrix as a double pointer in C, how to move through it

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have a function that looks like this:

```
int matrix(int **A, int rows, int coloums) {}
```

**how do I move through a matrix that looks like this?**

I am used to work with matrix as bidimensional Arrays and have two indexes (e.g i,j) and two `for` cycles to move through.

But I am not sure how to work with double pointers, even though I know they basically point to a location in memory.

Comment: You do it just the same way as for arrays of arrays, with two nested `for` loops.

Comment: ok but how about the length? can you provide an example?

Comment: But don't the `row` and `column` variables provide the length? While `A` isn't really an array of arrays, in many cases you can treat it as such.

Comment: ok thanks I will try this way

Comment: Note: This is not a _double pointer_, rather, a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: ok Thanks for the note. I am quite new to C so I still have got a lot to learn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a double pointer be used for a two dimensional matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900851/how-can-a-double-pointer-be-used-for-a-two-dimensional-matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you'd index it like any 2D array:  `A[i][j]`.

Array subscripting is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic.  The expression `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)` - that is, given the address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (**not bytes**) from that address<sup>1</sup> and dereference the result.

Arrays are not pointers, but array *expressions* will be converted ("decay") to pointer expressions under most circumstances<sup>2</sup>.  When the compiler sees an expression like `a[i]`, it will first convert the *expression* `a` from type "N-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and then apply the subscript operation to that pointer value, so `a[i] == *(a + i)`.

This means you can also use the subscript operator on things that are already pointers:

```
int a[N];
int *p = a;
...
p[i] = some_value();
```

It's evaluated in exactly the same way - `*(p + i)`.  The only difference is that there's no need to convert `p` from an array type to a pointer type.

Since the subscript operator dereferences the pointer, this means that for any expression `a` of type `T *`, the expression `a[i]` has type `T`.  Applying this to your code:

```
Expression            Type
----------            ----
         A            int **
      A[i]            int *
   A[i][j]            int
```

This all assumes that `A` was allocated as a pointer to a sequence of pointers:

```
int **A = malloc( sizeof *A * rows );
if ( A )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  {
    A[i] = malloc( sizeof *A[i] * cols );
  }
}
```

---

1. Pointer arithmetic takes the type of the pointed-to object into account.  Given a pointer `T *p;`, the expression `p + i` gives the address of the `i`<sup>th</sup> *object* of type `T` following `p`.

   Except when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Very clear and helpful!